# swiftの値の格納方法について

Tags: swift

```
var a: Int = { 10 + 20 }() // (1)
var b: Int { return 10 + 20 } // (2)

println(a)
println(b)
```

上記コードの場合、変数a, bともに30と表示されます。

(1)はclosureの結果がaに格納されていると理解できるのですが、(2)でbに値が入るのが理解できません。

(2)もclosureなのでしょうか？
なぜ「=」がないのでしょうか？
なぜ式の末尾に「()」がないのでしょうか？

ご教授お願い致します。

また、参考になるサイトがあれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2)は、**Computed Property**（計算プロパティ）です。省略せず定義を記述すると、

```
var b: Int {
    get {
        return 10 + 20
    }
}
```

Computed Propertyの定義は、基本Getter（`get {}`）とSetter（`set() {}`）がセットになりますが、Setterは省略可能で、省略した場合、ご質問にあるように、

```
var b: Int { return 10 + 20 }
```

という省略構文が使えます。

> また、参考になるサイトがあれば教えて下さい。

Apple Developer
[The Swift Programming Language - Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)